# How to use OdbcParameter for MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How to use OdbcParameter for **MySQL**?

**This is my current attempt**:

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@username", username.Text));
command.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@password", password.Text));
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.test (`user`,`password`) VALUES (@username,@password);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

but it seems to be not working. The database does create a new row, but it's values are NULL.

**This works**: (but I really need the parameters for other stuff)

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.test (`user`,`password`) VALUES (`" + username.Text + "`,`" + password.Text + "`);";
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: I hope this was a contrived example - please never store passwords as their text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your `CommandText` to be a valid one for OdbcCommand:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO test.test (`user`,`password`) VALUES (? , ?);";
```

Instead of the parameter name as `@paramname`, it takes a `?` in the `CommandText` - leave the name in the actual parameters.

See [this](http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/addparameterizedqueriesinmysqloledb.aspx) blog post for an example.